# Profile Completion e-mail to user in Drupal

Tags: drupal

How can I have Drupal 6 send a reminder e-mail to users who did not complete their profile information?

Is there a module available to do this? I think we can do it using Rules/Trigger, but not exactly. I need something similar to what cron jobs do in PHP.

Comment: Flagging for move to [drupal.se](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/)